# WiFi IP filtering?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip-address, mac-address

Is it possible for a WiFi host to filter WiFi service by a computer's local IP, similar to how it's possible to filter WiFi clients by MAC Address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a WiFi host, or router, will actually assign each client an individual IP address.  However, most WiFi routers and access points are either firewalls or connected to a firewall.  A [firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall) can be configured to filter traffic based on IP address, however I don't see that happening at the WiFi level.

Answer (score 1):

The wireless router provides the computer's IP address, so I do not think this would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The wifi driver receives the packets, pass them to the hardware to decrypt it and driver gets the real data packets, and it can read the IP header. If you want to filter out some client like MAC address filering, you must modify the wifi driver yourself and add some code to do this thing.

`Hardware RX -> wifi driver -> IP filter function -> Upper layer.`

But it  violates the 4-layer module, so it is not suggested to do this work.
You need also add a user space ioctl interface in wifi driver to control it.